# Binary search to find interval containing a given point

Tags: binary-search-tree, binary-search

I have a list of arrays of varying size, each representing an interval by maintaining a min and max. When the data is dense, it can be assumed that an interval's min is close to the previous interval's max, but they never overlap.

I would like to determine which interval a point belongs to with as few as possible comparisons. What I think is a naive approach is to compare again the min first, and go left is less than. Otherwise compare against the max and go right if greater, otherwise we have found the interval. I'm wondering whether I can instead compare to the median of each interval and go either left or right without comparing against the min and max at first. When the range of the search becomes 0, my theory is that I can then compare against the min of the successor to determine which interval is correct. So it's like an eager branch strategy that avoids the double comparison per interval, but I'm not sure if there is a valid eager solution that works.

What would be an optimal algorithm here? I've been reading a lot about segment trees (which I think is the closest to my problem) but haven't managed to find a solid reference for a smart binary search approach.

Intervals do not overlap and the list of intervals is sorted such that an intervals min is greater than its predecessor's max.